# Filling missing values along rows

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm an absolute R beginner so please bear with me as I try to explain! I am looking for a code that will essentially fill in the NA values in the far right column (edu2019) by using the last available value (working backwards from right to left). e.g. the edu2019 value for Aruba should be 8, whereas for Afghanistan it should be 35.1.

```
country_name                edu2014  edu2015  edu2016 edu2017 edu2018 edu2019
   <chr>                         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Aruba                          NA     NA     NA      NA      8         NA
 2 Africa Eastern and Southern    NA     NA     NA      NA      NA        NA
 3 Afghanistan                    34.6   34.7   35.2    35.0    35.1      NA
 4 Africa Western and Central     NA     NA     9       NA      7         NA
 5 Angola                         NA     NA     39.5    NA      NA        NA
 6 Albania                        46.6   46.9   47.1    47.1    47.1      50
```

I've tried copying suggested codes but I'm never sure what I should be adjusting to make it reflect my dataset and just end up getting error messages.

For example I attempted this

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(!edu2019, ~ replace(., is.na(.), invoke(coalesce, rev(df[-1])))))
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

EDITED TO INCLUDE ACTUAL DATA USING DPUT FUNCTION>

```
structure(list(country_name = c("Aruba", "Africa Eastern and Southern", 
"Afghanistan", "Africa Western and Central", "Angola", "Albania", 
"Andorra", "Arab World", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "American Samoa", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Burundi", "Belgium", "Benin", "Burkina Faso", 
"Bangladesh", "Bulgaria", "Bahrain", "Bahamas, The", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Belarus", "Belize", "Bermuda", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Barbados", 
"Brunei Darussalam", "Bhutan", "Botswana", "Central African Republic", 
"Canada", "Central Europe and the Baltics", "Switzerland", "Channel Islands", 
"Chile", "China", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cameroon", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", 
"Congo, Rep.", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Cabo Verde", "Costa Rica", 
"Caribbean small states", "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cayman Islands", 
"Cyprus", "Czechia", "Germany", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Denmark", 
"Dominican Republic", "Algeria", "East Asia & Pacific (excluding high income)", 
"Early-demographic dividend", "East Asia & Pacific", "Europe & Central Asia (excluding high income)", 
"Europe & Central Asia", "Ecuador", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", "Euro area", 
"Eritrea", "Spain", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "European Union", 
"Fragile and conflict affected situations", "Finland", "Fiji", 
"France", "Faroe Islands", "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.", "Gabon", 
"United Kingdom", "Georgia", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Guinea", 
"Gambia, The", "Guinea-Bissau", "Equatorial Guinea", "Greece", 
"Grenada", "Greenland", "Guatemala", "Guam", "Guyana", "High income", 
"Hong Kong SAR, China", "Honduras", "Heavily indebted poor countries (HIPC)", 
"Croatia", "Haiti", "Hungary", "IBRD only", "IDA & IBRD total", 
"IDA total", "IDA blend", "Indonesia", "IDA only", "Isle of Man", 
"India", "Not classified", "Ireland", "Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Iraq", 
"Iceland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Kenya", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Cambodia", "Kiribati", "St. Kitts and Nevis", 
"Korea, Rep.", "Kuwait", "Latin America & Caribbean (excluding high income)", 
"Lao PDR", "Lebanon", "Liberia", "Libya", "St. Lucia", "Latin America & Caribbean", 
"Least developed countries: UN classification", "Low income", 
"Liechtenstein", "Sri Lanka", "Lower middle income", "Low & middle income", 
"Lesotho", "Late-demographic dividend", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", 
"Latvia", "Macao SAR, China", "St. Martin (French part)", "Morocco", 
"Monaco", "Moldova", "Madagascar", "Maldives", "Middle East & North Africa", 
"Mexico", "Marshall Islands", "Middle income", "North Macedonia", 
"Mali", "Malta", "Myanmar", "Middle East & North Africa (excluding high income)", 
"Montenegro", "Mongolia", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Mozambique", 
"Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "North America", 
"Namibia", "New Caledonia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Nicaragua", 
"Netherlands", "Norway", "Nepal", "Nauru", "New Zealand", "OECD members", 
"Oman", "Other small states", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Poland", "Pre-demographic dividend", 
"Puerto Rico", "Korea, Dem. People's Rep.", "Portugal", "Paraguay", 
"West Bank and Gaza", "Pacific island small states", "Post-demographic dividend", 
"French Polynesia", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russian Federation", 
"Rwanda", "South Asia", "Saudi Arabia", "Sudan", "Senegal", "Singapore", 
"Solomon Islands", "Sierra Leone", "El Salvador", "San Marino", 
"Somalia", "Serbia", "Sub-Saharan Africa (excluding high income)", 
"South Sudan", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Small states", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Suriname", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Sweden", "Eswatini", 
"Sint Maarten (Dutch part)", "Seychelles", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Turks and Caicos Islands", "Chad", "East Asia & Pacific (IDA & IBRD countries)", 
"Europe & Central Asia (IDA & IBRD countries)", "Togo", "Thailand", 
"Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Latin America & the Caribbean (IDA & IBRD countries)", 
"Timor-Leste", "Middle East & North Africa (IDA & IBRD countries)", 
"Tonga", "South Asia (IDA & IBRD)", "Sub-Saharan Africa (IDA & IBRD countries)", 
"Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkiye", "Tuvalu", "Tanzania", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "Upper middle income", "Uruguay", "United States", 
"Uzbekistan", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "Venezuela, RB", 
"British Virgin Islands", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Vietnam", 
"Vanuatu", "World", "Samoa", "Kosovo", "Yemen, Rep.", "South Africa", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), edu2014 = c(NA, NA, 34.62152, NA, NA, 
46.59472, 47.99722, 46.95668, NA, 50.7961, 48.02877, NA, 49.68429, 
NA, 47.79125, NA, 46.747, 52.10666, 40.22902, 45.73683, NA, 47.6472, 
48.93997, 50.63918, 49.23015, 48.17537, 51.07427, 52.47984, 48.7912, 
50.50958, 49.54133, 48.12994, 50.98684, NA, NA, 48.7426, 48.31178, 
NA, NA, 49.34039, 47.35246, 41.01643, 45.68476, 38.15109, NA, 
50.8991, 50.81869, 52.70548, 50.22543, 51.01624, 48.98353, NA, 
NA, 48.92554, 48.78077, 47.36128, 44.16341, 49.01995, 49.60066, 
51.90523, NA, 47.9515, 48.26262, 47.951, 48.33135, 48.55817, 
50.04557, 48.56597, 48.5191, 44.20559, 48.75095, 48.47893, NA, 
48.75428, 43.30865, 51.22522, NA, 49.15044, NA, NA, NA, 49.80458, 
47.82937, 47.35436, NA, 39.12257, NA, NA, NA, 47.54822, 48.77773, 
NA, 47.792, NA, NA, 48.55242, 47.53024, 53.09116, 44.61334, 49.61307, 
NA, 48.79058, 48.29303, 47.88779, 46.23953, 45.46515, 48.56827, 
46.66929, NA, 47.64562, NA, 49.32637, 47.52331, NA, 49.7069, 
49.02146, 48.12078, 50.73687, 50.28967, 48.85964, 49.39323, NA, 
49.20463, NA, NA, 50.06865, 47.70265, 49.84898, 50.49931, 46.9577, 
51.43982, 43.00246, NA, 49.82309, 50.47885, 46.41229, 44.59565, 
44.70032, NA, 47.70174, 47.88895, 57.32367, 48.3204, 47.56462, 
49.22768, 47.90591, 47.85986, NA, NA, 48.78444, 49.02207, 49.52351, 
NA, 47.13528, 50.79245, NA, 48.15605, 47.88157, 41.99081, 49.55673, 
50.43857, 47.49039, NA, NA, NA, 47.61598, 47.05534, 49.69812, 
47.46204, 50.48883, 49.10564, NA, NA, 41.32214, 46.33311, NA, 
NA, 47.67832, 50.44887, 49.02724, 50.1406, 48.95586, NA, 49.61774, 
42.30656, 50.92779, 48.6534, 50.58583, 49.50125, NA, 47.85073, 
43.87272, 49.60632, NA, 48.84112, NA, 51.31777, NA, 48.72777, 
NA, 48.0501, 48.43397, 48.23819, 52.49162, 47.49713, NA, 47.03162, 
49.61256, NA, NA, NA, 49.7509, NA, NA, 49.07399, 45.9443, NA, 
45.94482, 49.92218, 51.90344, 56.278, 49.02453, 48.44296, 51.60192, 
49.58809, 49.98157, 49.9519, NA, 50.41414, 30.85782, 47.93301, 
48.31127, NA, 50.14043, NA, 48.38187, 50.5025, 50.71257, 47.39748, 
49.80282, 47.49713, 45.94482, NA, NA, 48.41458, 52.95587, 48.76969, 
NA, 48.21119, 48.69495, NA, 49.14494, 48.58767, 48.68497, 50.8361, 
51.93759, NA, NA, NA, 47.99342, 50.88899, NA, NA, 51.91481, NA, 
NA), ...60 = c(NA, NA, 34.69429, NA, NA, 46.86349, 47.69056, 
47.07118, NA, 50.60901, 47.55359, NA, 50, 45.21232, 47.84602, 
NA, 48.43815, 52.12979, 41.04859, 47.05256, 51.89476, 47.69485, 
48.87295, 50.37258, 49.28957, 48.2817, 50.50983, 51.95545, 48.62389, 
50.24987, 49.58159, 48.346, 50.85307, NA, NA, 48.75683, 48.38357, 
47.83439, NA, 49.28201, 47.34064, 41.40705, 45.81841, 38.80093, 
NA, 50.70187, NA, 52.22395, 49.86985, 50.84623, 49.29587, NA, 
NA, 48.86549, 48.90303, 47.29219, 43.94533, 49.16382, 49.68921, 
51.79523, NA, 47.90167, 48.25398, 47.90091, 48.34757, 48.53424, 
49.97037, NA, 48.4694, 45.15268, 48.55977, 48.52522, 48.45785, 
48.70241, 43.81298, 51.22698, NA, 49.04913, NA, NA, NA, 49.59595, 
47.57624, 47.60539, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.25979, 48.75927, NA, 
47.59989, NA, NA, 48.52552, 47.4898, 53.5367, 45.04366, 49.8605, 
NA, 48.76099, 48.19379, 47.86408, 46.57627, 45.59024, 48.78793, 
47.1265, NA, 47.59985, NA, 49.47811, 47.55864, NA, 49.14716, 
48.88041, 48.09331, 50.56599, NA, 48.82512, 49.57684, NA, 49.36953, 
NA, NA, 50.74108, 47.74147, 49.70154, 50.41137, 47.27747, 51.02124, 
42.85374, NA, 49.73137, 50.38875, 46.88693, 44.88739, 44.10272, 
NA, 47.76575, 47.86594, 57.12187, 48.18399, 47.56878, 49.59066, 
48.25876, 48.03244, NA, NA, 49.19624, 48.84764, 49.70281, NA, 
47.12234, 50.99047, 50.3117, 48.11105, 48.15319, 43.61438, 50.1359, 
NA, 47.46732, 48.25466, NA, NA, 47.9285, 47.46215, 50.262, 47.7728, 
50.63376, 49.13223, NA, NA, 41.48005, 46.9195, NA, 49.09752, 
47.92183, 50.57863, NA, 50.07354, 48.96498, 48.82363, 49.6271, 
42.31326, 50.42111, 48.77564, 50.35619, NA, NA, 47.90157, 44.31603, 
49.44007, 49.14544, 48.64942, NA, 51.31811, NA, 48.70785, NA, 
48.35456, 48.54449, 48.23725, 52.22141, 47.49095, 48.64773, 49.02261, 
NA, NA, NA, 46.74976, 49.71839, NA, NA, 48.91535, 46.08228, 34.49112, 
46.08285, 49.87941, 52.15839, 55.17991, 48.99434, 48.5148, 51.62798, 
49.77213, NA, 50.63565, NA, 51.56483, 30.79583, 47.88236, 48.33251, 
NA, 47.78832, NA, NA, 50.40757, 50.64262, 47.37287, 48.91139, 
47.49095, 46.08285, NA, NA, 48.40957, 53.52987, 49.47021, NA, 
48.31709, 48.53337, NA, 49.17237, 48.59321, 48.7167, 50.82308, 
51.35668, NA, NA, 48.95955, 47.96893, 50.7117, NA, NA, 49.29703, 
NA, NA), ...61 = c(NA, NA, 35.18667, NA, 39.52354, 47.07269, 
49.12994, 47.06386, 48.60796, 50.25036, NA, NA, NA, 45.19242, 
47.77079, NA, 49.9138, 51.69941, 42.41021, 47.80332, 51.36834, 
47.72228, 48.88571, 50.53904, 49.28292, 48.24317, 50.17785, NA, 
48.50505, 49.96678, 49.79872, 48.6828, 51.54652, NA, 39.29494, 
48.87042, 48.3764, 47.76601, NA, 49.28981, 47.11396, 41.90515, 
45.89873, NA, NA, 50.53435, NA, 52.04053, 50.19909, 50.68381, 
49.37618, NA, NA, 48.73903, 48.87799, 47.12005, 44.47654, NA, 
49.28619, 51.61995, NA, 47.94401, 48.40487, 47.93998, 48.37179, 
48.52626, 49.77575, 48.18645, 48.44267, NA, 48.7454, 48.8306, 
NA, 48.66753, 44.07258, 51.20837, NA, 49.01155, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
47.30988, 48.08399, 48.47619, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.41126, 49.72237, 
NA, 47.70198, NA, NA, 48.41388, 47.50336, 52.91045, 45.23154, 
49.79285, NA, 48.37934, 48.24049, 47.91316, 46.66398, 45.58855, 
49.39896, 47.2376, NA, 47.68043, NA, 49.4879, 47.94755, NA, 49.11223, 
49.04498, 48.20486, 50.06342, NA, 48.82915, 49.36763, NA, 49.00685, 
NA, NA, 51.4012, 47.72339, NA, 50.28362, 47.34442, 51.23687, 
NA, NA, 50.13392, 50.26348, 46.97849, 45.05869, 44.10147, 50.76423, 
47.86566, 47.91539, 57.26666, 48.06615, 47.49392, 49.44567, 48.47129, 
48.24839, NA, NA, 48.14703, 48.5623, 49.80853, NA, 47.18566, 
51.14729, 50.29091, 48.15527, NA, 42.03535, 49.64901, 52.08868, 
47.52989, 48.24052, NA, NA, NA, 48.55742, 50.26755, 47.0801, 
50.13648, 48.79735, NA, NA, 42.06672, 46.57444, NA, 49.09864, 
47.96482, 50.55539, 50.40323, 50.23203, 48.89987, 48.20415, 49.68293, 
42.8194, 49.78045, 48.74217, 50.51536, NA, 40.67178, 48.00351, 
44.32239, 49.52521, NA, 48.60962, 50.3607, 51.36573, NA, 48.58696, 
NA, 48.97044, 48.4972, 48.39002, 52.53965, 47.57811, 47.11496, 
48.88794, NA, 48.50495, NA, 48.00626, 49.49582, NA, NA, 48.89012, 
46.27246, NA, 46.27311, 49.88498, 52.78065, NA, 48.99423, 48.85356, 
51.09626, 49.54566, NA, 51.5425, NA, NA, 31.27065, 47.9252, 48.36135, 
NA, 48.63439, NA, NA, 50.2778, 50.77245, 47.4355, NA, 47.57811, 
46.27311, NA, 51.36858, 48.43019, 52.71594, 49.86364, NA, 48.4481, 
48.51954, NA, 48.78903, 48.57865, 49.05604, 50.86024, 51.9174, 
NA, NA, NA, 47.99251, 50.66246, NA, 41.16112, 51.90365, NA, NA
), ...62 = c(NA, NA, 35.03392, NA, NA, 47.08215, 48.64203, 47.10866, 
46.65172, 50.17572, NA, NA, 48.76898, 45.77643, 47.65731, NA, 
51.20159, 51.68019, NA, 48.36088, 52.80007, 47.80224, 48.95992, 
50.74821, 49.30889, 48.26643, 50.9508, NA, 48.45873, 49.73256, 
49.61727, 48.92047, 51.66481, NA, 40.13015, 48.91224, 48.43757, 
47.67995, NA, 49.24016, 47.05148, 42.7095, NA, NA, NA, 50.32766, 
50.67833, 52.02678, 50.60972, 50.79623, 49.09229, NA, NA, 48.75752, 
48.87003, 46.73839, 44.93517, NA, 48.97225, 51.43398, NA, 47.89156, 
48.38188, 47.90316, 48.11254, 48.34826, 49.67107, 48.14735, 48.31893, 
46.47609, 48.99069, 49.31515, NA, 48.57243, 44.18438, 51.17456, 
NA, 48.94717, NA, NA, NA, 49.60724, 47.14191, 48.24081, 48.50814, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.52477, 50.07924, NA, 47.78891, NA, NA, 48.3879, 
47.49747, 52.4563, 45.39875, 49.86788, NA, 48.6227, 48.11102, 
47.86446, 46.93841, 45.61351, 49.20422, 47.63947, NA, 47.4799, 
NA, 48.58142, 48.02918, NA, 48.94628, 49.05267, 48.00923, 50.20531, 
50.30693, 48.80558, 48.95656, NA, 48.98972, NA, NA, NA, 47.78214, 
NA, 50.15203, 47.4067, 50.83173, NA, NA, 49.97135, 50.13873, 
47.40514, 45.19367, 44.81481, 51.21948, 47.87217, 47.86564, 57.37709, 
47.93876, 47.56718, 49.15061, 48.57532, 48.41117, NA, 45.99789, 
48.92002, 48.36115, 50.21101, NA, 47.17344, 51.0881, NA, 48.09595, 
47.84581, 44.06245, 48.67685, 52.03305, 47.53524, 48.08337, NA, 
NA, 47.51968, 49.39017, 50.79189, 48.41682, 49.88073, 48.82831, 
NA, NA, 41.91998, NA, NA, 49.01601, 47.60539, 51.2535, NA, 50.36605, 
48.81583, 48.76796, 49.78914, 42.83845, 50.45662, 48.77511, 50.82828, 
NA, NA, 48.07058, 44.47534, NA, NA, 48.63717, NA, 51.2936, NA, 
48.57116, NA, 49.03437, 48.65778, 48.21455, 53.10014, 47.54081, 
46.47537, 49.74245, 51.75372, 48.58072, NA, 49.08339, 49.34364, 
NA, NA, 48.78548, 46.40833, NA, 46.40897, 49.97588, 53.13623, 
NA, 49.03208, 48.87642, 50.05032, NA, NA, 51.77941, NA, NA, NA, 
47.87242, 48.12421, 41.95472, 47.73833, NA, NA, 50.15431, 51.00979, 
47.44128, NA, 47.54081, 46.40897, NA, NA, 47.79338, NA, 50.25993, 
NA, 48.60997, 48.37876, 51.56352, 48.81884, 48.56844, 48.28439, 
50.88421, 51.79601, NA, NA, NA, 47.94622, NA, NA, NA, 51.70123, 
NA, NA), ...63 = c(NA, NA, 35.12363, NA, NA, 47.09416, 48.34921, 
47.202, NA, NA, 47.26682, NA, 48.52342, NA, NA, 46.73612, 52.69295, 
NA, NA, 49.07022, 52.63983, NA, 48.80536, 51.74453, 49.39487, 
48.29377, 50.58608, NA, 48.45713, NA, 49.59379, 48.99839, 52.01454, 
NA, NA, NA, 48.44025, NA, NA, NA, 46.94867, 43.47853, NA, NA, 
NA, 50.22036, 50.78499, 52.22378, 50.68349, 50.60897, 48.99787, 
NA, 49.68354, NA, NA, NA, 45.12158, NA, NA, 51.26201, NA, 47.87101, 
48.43648, 47.87706, 48.09481, 48.34191, 49.67034, 48.222, 48.32282, 
46.72357, NA, NA, NA, 48.57699, 44.22324, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 47.28394, 48.54687, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.77559, 
NA, 47.83371, NA, NA, 48.38355, 47.56879, NA, 45.57916, NA, NA, 
NA, 48.10305, 47.88854, 47.09857, 45.96137, 49.17247, 47.70363, 
NA, 48.05586, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.71555, 50.35248, 
NA, 48.93286, NA, 49.0348, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.1499, 47.56735, 
51.19602, NA, NA, 49.77103, 50.13663, 47.44486, 45.30684, NA, 
51.11506, 47.94685, 47.88991, NA, 47.88807, NA, NA, NA, 48.2975, 
NA, 46.56576, 48.9784, 48.3041, 50.60593, NA, 47.25132, NA, NA, 
48.11523, NA, 44.48754, NA, 51.90363, 47.61761, 48.03013, NA, 
NA, NA, 49.71302, 50.41822, 49.53251, 50.48053, 48.82823, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.8168, 48.60193, 49.76112, 
44.01411, NA, 48.8549, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.62379, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 51.44826, NA, 48.56998, NA, 48.94687, NA, NA, 53.156, 47.60807, 
47.58781, NA, 51.87243, NA, NA, NA, 49.35867, 44.46461, NA, 48.84442, 
46.51831, NA, 46.5188, 49.91619, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
50.63681, NA, 49.65458, NA, 47.85229, 48.10727, NA, 48.19721, 
NA, NA, 50.15311, 51.32771, 47.52165, NA, 47.60807, 46.5188, 
NA, NA, NA, 51.97429, 50.82547, NA, 48.657, 48.33152, NA, NA, 
NA, 48.91925, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.9647, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), edu2019 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45.77627, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.88477, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 48.956, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.76261, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51.43063, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -266L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I would suggest pivoting your data using `pivot_longer()`, then using `fill()` to fill in the missing values, and then pivoting back to wide format with `pivot_wider()`. All functions are from {tidyr}. If you can add the data to your post with `dput()` , it makes it easier for someone to show an example of how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @nrennie's suggestion

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf |> 
  rename(edu2015 = ...60, edu2016 = ...61, edu2017 = ...62, edu2018 = ...63) |> 
  pivot_longer(-country_name) |> 
  group_by(country_name) |> 
  fill(value, .direction = "down") |> 
  ungroup() |>
  pivot_wider()      

# A tibble: 266 × 7
   country_name                edu2014 edu2015 edu2016 edu2017 edu2018 edu2019
   <chr>                         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Aruba                          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  
 2 Africa Eastern and Southern    NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  
 3 Afghanistan                    34.6    34.7    35.2    35.0    35.1    35.1
 4 Africa Western and Central     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  
 5 Angola                         NA      NA      39.5    39.5    39.5    39.5
 6 Albania                        46.6    46.9    47.1    47.1    47.1    47.1
 7 Andorra                        48.0    47.7    49.1    48.6    48.3    48.3
 8 Arab World                     47.0    47.1    47.1    47.1    47.2    47.2
 9 United Arab Emirates           NA      NA      48.6    46.7    46.7    46.7
10 Argentina                      50.8    50.6    50.3    50.2    50.2    50.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply`, with `MARGIN=1` for row-wise, you could `na.omit` each row while excluding country and extract first element of `tail`. Then `replace` all `NA`s either with that value or with `NA` if there are no non-`NA`s. We can check first `if` `anyNA` to skip non-missing rows. Finally just `rbind` ans `as.data.frame` with a `type.convert` since `apply` coerces to matrix.

```
res <- t(apply(dat, MARGIN=1, \(x) {
  if (anyNA(x)) {
    tx <- tail(na.omit(x[-1]), 1)
    replace(x, is.na(x), ifelse(length(tx), tx, NA))
  } else {
    x
  }
})) |> as.data.frame() |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)

head(res)
#                  country_name  edu2014    ...60    ...61    ...62    ...63  edu2019
# 1                       Aruba       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2 Africa Eastern and Southern       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 3                 Afghanistan 34.62152 34.69429 35.18667 35.03392 35.12363 35.12363
# 4  Africa Western and Central       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 5                      Angola 39.52354 39.52354 39.52354 39.52354 39.52354 39.52354
# 6                     Albania 46.59472 46.86349 47.07269 47.08215 47.09416 47.09416
```